# MySQL - How to select first string in group by clause by date

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Given this transactions table

```
ID Date Name Stat1
1  1     a     1
1  2     b     1
1  3     c     1 
2  4     d     1
2  5     e     1
```

I want to group the records by ID, and have the column 'Name' per group ID to show the last name by date as it is appears in table (high number in date is chronologically last). final result:

```
ID Date Name Stat1
1  3     c    3 
2  5     e    2
```

Unfortunately this code:

```
Select ID,Date,Name,sum(Stat1)
From myTable
Group by ID
```

will generate "random" name,
how do i force choose the first/last record name(by date) in each group (ID)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a query like this.

Change min to max if you want to have the first or last row of a group:

```
SELECT
  result.id,
  result.mdate,
  mt.name,
  result.stat1
FROM (
  Select
    ID,
    min(date) mdate,
    sum(Stat1) as stat1
  From myTable
  Group by ID
) AS result
LEFT JOIN myTable mt 
ON    mt.id = result.id
AND mt.date = result.mdate;
```